# "script" step in Jenkinsfile - Permission denied

Tags: jenkins, vagrant

Can anyone explain, why I'm getting "Permission denied" in "script" step ?

I run this Jenkins job as user `vagrant`.
Am even printing all the information: it is indeed `vagrant` user, belongs to `fred` group which is the owner of `/opt/ab/cd/tests/` folder. But despite that can not do anything, like basic `mkdir`

```
stage('Run tests') {
   BDD_RESULTS = sh (
      script: '(pushd /opt/ab/cd/tests/; whoami; groups vagrant; ls -la; mkdir my_test || true; popd)',
      returnStdout: true
   )
   println "BDD=$BDD_RESULTS"
   ...
}
```

result:

```
+ whoami
+ groups vagrant
+ ls -la
+ mkdir my_test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘my_test’: Permission denied
+ true
+ popd
[Pipeline] echo
BDD=/opt/ab/cd/tests/ ~/.jenkins/workspace/test-build
vagrant
vagrant : vagrant redis fred
drwxrwxr-x. 4 fred fred   179 Apr  1 21:13 .
drwxrwxr-x. 7 fred fred    92 Apr  1 21:13 ..
~/.jenkins/workspace/test-build
```

This `mkdir` is just an example, not exactly what I try to do this way, of course.

If I set permissions on that `tests` folder to `777`, then it is working. But I would like to keep `775`.

I'm running Jenkins with this command: `java -jar /home/vagrant/jenkins.war &> /home/vagrant/jenkins.out&`, CentOS 7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your scripts under the `script` block and then try.

Something like this

```yaml
pipeline {

   stages {
      stage('Run tests') { 
         steps { 
            script {

                  BDD_RESULTS = sh (
      script: '(pushd /opt/ab/cd/tests/; whoami; groups vagrant; ls -la; mkdir my_test || true; popd)',
      returnStdout: true
   )
   println "BDD=$BDD_RESULTS"
   ...

   }
  }
 }
}
```