# Groovy error while executing shell script in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins Pipeline using Groovy sandbox. And I am trying to run a shell script inside a groovy sh function but facing error as mentioned below. Any help will be highly appreciable.

`WorkflowScript: 13: unexpected token: @ @ line 13, column 55. for i in "${!project_list[@]}"`

Code is as below.

```
#!groovy
node('test'){
    
    stage('Scanning') 
    {   
          if (scanParam != "" && scanParam == "Yes" && currentBranch == "dev")
              {
                 withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'AUTH_TOKEN', variable: 'SECRET')])
                   {
                      sh """
                            echo $WORKSPACE
                            declare -A project_list=(["TestProject"]="10234")
                            for i in "${!project_list[\@\]}"
                              do
                                project_name=$i
                                project_app_version=${project_list[$i]}
                              done
                        """
                   }
            }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Put the whole script under `script { }` block, similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912044/script-step-in-jenkinsfile-permission-denied and then try

Comment: Also, here are you trying to escape the `@` character ?

Comment: But not escape the `$` in the for loop?

Comment: Switching from `"""` to `'''` should save a lot of your issues, as you are not templating the string with values from Groovy