# Execute shell script from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to execute shell script from my jenkins pipeline. I have provided absolute and relative path in the shell command and still I am facing `No such file or directory` error while building the pipeline.

This is simple script but yet not working.

**Try 1:**

```
         stage ( 'Executing shell script' ) {
             steps {
                     sh '/home/patching/shell_script.sh'
                     
                     }
                   }
```

**Try 2:**

```
         stage ( 'Executing shell script' ) {
             steps {
                     sh './shell_script.sh'
                     
                     }
                   }
```

**Try 3:**

```
         stage ( 'Executing shell script' ) {
             steps {
                     dir ('/home/patching/shell_script.sh){
                         sh './shell_script.sh'
                   }
                }
```

I really don't know what is really wrong with the script. Could some one help me on this?

Comment: Have you checked the correct user permission is given to `shell_script.sh` ?

Comment: I have given rwx to all users and groups for this file.. also root owns this file

Comment: Then try placing your script inside `script{ }` block. Have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912044/script-step-in-jenkinsfile-permission-denied/66914383#66914383

Comment: get the workspace folder of the job, see which directory you're presently in. there is no harm in running a sequence of shell commands like `pwd, find, ls etc...` that would help you get the path of the script and run the same.

Comment: @SouravAtta its not working.. i tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue why it wasn't able to find the file that I wanted to run. It was running on different slave.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Hello World') {
        steps {
            script {
               sh '''
               
                /home/ubuntu/First.sh
               
               
               '''
                
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```